# Create a new SQLite table in python with for-loop

Tags: python, sqlite

Say I have 100 different integers I want to store like a row with 100 columns.

I am trying it like this:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nums(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
''')
for i in range(100):
    c.execute('''
    ALTER TABLE nums
    ADD ''' + 'column_' + i + '''INTEGER''')

db.commit()
```

Someone told me that when you are using numbers as column names you could probably do it a better way. But if I for example have a list with strings in python, and I want to loop through them and store every individual string in its own column, the approach would be the same, right?

However, this code runs without errors for me, but no new table is created, how come?

Comment: Remove the `,` after `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Also you need a space between i and INTEGER in your ATLER statement

Comment: "Someone" is absolutely right. If you have a set of names created by a number sequence, you are probably not following best practices. But in your cases the problem sits a little deeper: the wrong approach is in your own requirements already: "I want to […] store every individual string in its own column".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ALTER statement is incorrect as it's missing the COLUMN after ADD. You can use the following:

```
for i in range(100):
    c.execute(f'ALTER TABLE nums ADD COLUMN column_{i} INTEGER')
```